# Apache with c# classes

Tags: c#, apache, webserver, configure

Is there any way to have apache "pass" the request it takes to a c# "application" to handle, allowing it to return specific content. I want to handle an intense amount of asynchronous calls to apache via javascript and have these calls routed through c# (much the way asp.net does). Has anyone successfully done this before? Any idea where to start looking?

**Update**:
Some more information. I want to be able to handle thousands of concurrent asynchronous requests as fast as can possibly occur writing the interpreting agent in some kind of threaded c# application. I could be wrong, but I dont think that iis with asp.net is tailored for this sort of thing (a proof of concept would be great).

I feel that going with something like apache would be better suited. If that means going from something else to c# first is fine I guess, but I would like to be more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Apache actually supports running C# libraries using [mod mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono).  Also, you could use CURL to send a web request to C# running on IIS.  Another way would be to open a server socket directly in C#, and have apache (via php, python, or some other scripting language) connect to you C# application to handle the request. I think you need to be more specific about what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

with apache2, you could run [mod_aspdotnet](http://mod-aspdotnet.sourceforge.net/introduction.html)

or if it suits you, run some urls in proxy mode (pass them to another asp.net server), using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)

or [Kibbee's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114434/apache-with-c-classes/2114464#2114464)